what is the expected behavior of dismiss() when called by a navDestination's view?
In the code below, following the prompts, Click to select entry -> Click to populate linkedUuid, the top screen gets dismissed and goes back to the Home screen. Since dismiss() is called inside ShowAccounts view, I thought only ShowAccounts or SelectEntry gets dismissed, leaving Text("NavDest: Text-1") in tact.
The code does not behave as I expect. What Am I misunderstanding here? Thank you.

struct SO1_GAUsername: View {
    let SRC = "SO1_GAUsername"
    
    //=== Local ===
    @State private var linkedUuid: String? = "<???>"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(SRC)
        
        HStack {
            Text("LinkEntry")
            
            Text(linkedUuid!)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
        }
        
        LinkEntry(linkedUuid: $linkedUuid)
    } // body
    
    struct LinkEntry: View {
        let SRC = "LinkEntry"
        
        //=== Interface ===
        @Binding var linkedUuid: String?
        
        //=== Local ===
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) @Binding private var presentationMode
        
        @State private var showSelectEntry = false

        var body: some View {
            let _ = print("\(SRC): Called")
            
            Button("Click to select entry") {
                showSelectEntry = true
            }
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showSelectEntry) {
                Text("NavDest: Text-1")
                
                SelectEntry(linkedUuid: $linkedUuid)
            } // navDest
        } // body
    } // LinkEntry
    
    struct SelectEntry: View {
        let SRC = "SelectEntry"
        
        //=== Interface ===
        @Binding var linkedUuid: String?
        
        //=== Local ===
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) @Binding private var presentationMode

        var body: some View {
            let _ = print("\(SRC): Called")
            ShowAccounts(linkedUuid: $linkedUuid)
        } // body
    } // SelectEntry
    
    struct ShowAccounts: View {
        let SRC = "ShowAccounts"
        
        //=== Interface ===
        @Binding var linkedUuid: String?
        
        //=== Local ===
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) @Binding private var presentationMode
        
        var body: some View {
            let _ = print("\(SRC): Called")
            
            Button("\(SRC): Click to populate linkedUuid") {
                let SRC = self.SRC + ".Button.click"
                
                linkedUuid = "123xyz"
                
                print("\(SRC): Dismissing")
                presentationMode.dismiss()
            }
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
        } // body
    } // ShowAccounts
} // SO1_GAUsername




get rid of the Binding on the Environment also switch to dismiss vs presentationMode it seems like you are following some old guidance

dismiss has been notoriously giving me many unpredictable infinite loops. That is the reason why I reluctantly use presentationMode instead; the latter is not completely safe either.

Per Apple's doc, dismiss can be used to:

Dismiss a modal presentation, like a sheet or a popover.
Pop the current view from a NavigationStack.

That is, dismiss() removes the entire containing view (screen), not just a contained view. Thus, the behavior described in the question is correct.
